# Checkbox for the VB6 DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, vb6

[image]

How to add Checkbox for Vb6 data grid like as image.

Comment: Sure doesn't look like a DataGrid.  More like one of the FlexGrids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `MSFlexGrid` control, I use a checked and unchecked image in the column.

You add two `PictureBox`controls, one for each image, and make the `Visible` property false. When loading the data for your grid you can set each pic according to whether it needs to be checked or not:

```
With MSFlexGrid1
   .Col = 1
   If myCol1Bool Then
      Set .CellPicture = picChecked.Picture
   Else
      Set .CellPicture = picUnChecked.Picture
   End If
   .Col = 2
   If myCol2Bool Then
      Set .CellPicture = picChecked.Picture
   Else
      Set .CellPicture = picUnChecked.Picture
   End If
End With
```

You can toggle the check state on click if it's editable:

```
Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_Click()
    If (MSFlexGrid1.Col <> 1 And MSFlexGrid1.Col <> 2) Or MSFlexGrid1.Row < 1 Then Exit Sub

    If MSFlexGrid1.CellPicture = picChecked Then
        Set MSFlexGrid1.CellPicture = picUnchecked
    Else
        Set MSFlexGrid1.CellPicture = picChecked
    End If
End Sub
```

For a full example, check out [vb-helper.com](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_checkgrid.html).